# Couldn’t handle browser pop up for flash application using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have to test Flash application using selenium, but I am stuck with browsers pop up alerts which I couldn’t handle using Alerts class/ chrome options/ option.addarguments/desired capabilities/ can’t use key operation/ tab / no default alerts is highlighted/ can’t inspect/ any solution please

I have tried chrome and Firefox, Firefox bot  “version 60” is not even  even not loading the application when run my script To load the application.

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notification", 2);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS,true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
driver.get("");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
Alert.accept();
```

Selenium version is 3.14 Chrome Browser 73 Firefox version 60 JDK 11

Comment: Please post your code you have tried in your selenium script and the HTML for the page you are testing. What error(s) are you getting, if any?  What language is your script written in?

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself where it will be much easier to read.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. Also, do not post code (or pertinent info) in comments; just directly edit your question.  And please...no screeenshots.  Lastly...selenium cannot automate flash-based web apps.

Comment: I am using Java, no error found when I run my script for just to load the application and login then browser pop up ask me if I want to run the Flash application click on Allow or deny, I am not able to handle that pop up on chrome. Firefox is even not loading application.  I tried to change browser setting and allow to run Flash application always don’t ask.